# server side data validation with nesting

Tags: php

I cannot figure out why my nesting here is not working. Whenever I run this it goes straight to 'Incorrect password' (with all the fields blank) even though the condition about string length that proceeds it, is false. A reading of 'Email and password are required' is what I want to happen first. THEN if the email doesn't contain an @ sign, the @ notification, THEN the password notification. But it keeps jumping over my previous if statements. I know the nesting must be wrong, and I've re-arranged it many times. The only way it works is to remove the @ verification line completely, but I need to have it.

```
if ( isset($_POST['who']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ) {

    if ( strlen($_POST['who']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['pass']) < 1 ) {
       $failure = "E-mail and password are required"; 
    }
    if(stripos($_POST['who'],'@') === false && strlen($_POST['who'] > 1)) {
        $failure = "E-mail must have an at-sign (@)";
    }

    else {
       $check = hash('md5', $salt.$_POST['pass']);
          if ( $check == $stored_hash ) {
          // Redirect the browser to auto.php
          header("Location: auto.php?name=".urlencode($_POST['who']));
          return;
          } else {
          $failure = "Incorrect password";
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Warning!** _Don't use the md5 for password hashing!_ The [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) even warns you about it: _"It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm." You should use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate a secure hash and [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify the passwords against the hashes.

Comment: OK, but any thoughts on the nesting??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put 2nd if condition in else block. think about when password was blank but email was entered. it will bypass 2nd if block and go to else use like blow code

```
if ( isset($_POST['who']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ) {

 if ( strlen($_POST['who']) <= 1 || strlen($_POST['pass']) < 1 ) {
   $failure = "E-mail and password are required"; 
 } 
 else { 
  if(stripos($_POST['who'],'@') === false && strlen($_POST['who'] > 1)) {
     $failure = "E-mail must have an at-sign (@)";
  }

  else {
     $check = hash('md5', $salt.$_POST['pass']);
      if ( $check == $stored_hash ) {
        // Redirect the browser to auto.php
        header("Location: auto.php?name=".urlencode($_POST['who']));
        return;
      } else {
        $failure = "Incorrect password";
      }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the `&& strlen($_POST['who'] > 1` from the `elseif` condition, or you will still have the same issue if the `who` is one character long (since it only checks if it is less or grater than one, but never handle if it is only one character). It's also not needed since you've checked that length in the first `if`-condition so can't be empty at that point.

Comment: Instead of having `<=` in the first `if`, just remove the `&& strlen($_POST['who'] > 1` from the second, since it's a useless check.